# Error while creating tenant by using java program

Tags: apache-pulsar

Creating rest API for tenant

```
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.apache.pulsar.common.policies.data.TenantInfo;

TenantInfo tenantInfo = new TenantInfo(new HashSet<>(adminRoles),new HashSet<>(allowedClusters));

admin.tenants().createTenant(tenantName, tenantInfo);
```

Error: Cannot instantiate the type TenantInfo

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```java
admin.tenants().createTenant(tenantName,
    TenantInfo.builder()
         .adminRoles(adminRoles)
         .allowedClsuters(allowedClusters)
         .build());
```